# Youtube homepage - how to detect a given video has closed captions?

Tags: youtube

On youtube, sometimes video thumbnail show small CC button showing that a video has closed captions. But it only works inside user channel as far as I know.

I created a chrome extension to get all video thumbnails on a webpage, and use a command tool `youtube-dl` to ask if given video has subtitles. Specific command is:

```
youtube-dl --list-subs https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=${video_id}
```

it works fine, but I am scared I might get blocked by youtube. Not sure exactly how `youtube-dl` works, but I guess it is making connection every time I run a command - so for every video thumbnail I get presented on youtube.

Now I wonder - how do deaf people get to closed captions videos? Does accesibility features by youtube give more information than is visible on the screen? Or does anyone have other idea how to always know if given video has closed captions or not?